# How to make a link in powershell using python?

Tags: python, powershell

I was wondering if anyone knows how to make if it is at all possible a link to a file in PowerShell so that I can just click on it and it opens the link/file automatically instead of me having to copy and paste the link which is what I am currently doing.

```
print(str(route)+"\\"+str(file))
```

returns something like

D:\Data\US\2019-06-27.xlsx

But I would like to just click on the link in powershell rather than have to manually copy and paste all the time

Comment: I don't think power shell supports clicking a file path and automatically changing directory/ running the program. It could be a big security issue by tricking someone to click on a malicious executable.

Comment: oh bother... do you have an ide that would allow this that you would reccomend?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "link to a file in PowerShell"? "So that I can just click on it" - click on what? What link are you copying and pasting, and where? (Remember, we can't see your screen!)

Comment: I think the OP wants when a program prints a path, like `D:\Data\US\2019-06-27.xlsx`, he wants for Excel to open that file when he clicks on it, like a hyperlink

Comment: If that is what the OP is asking, the OP could update the python to shell Excel with the filename as an argument instead of outputting the filename to the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of click links in the PowerShell consolehost.
You need to have a GUI, that you populate with links to click on.
For Example:

[PowerShell GUI: Create a Link Label using WinForms](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-GUI-Create-a-605d8c55)

[Download: link-label.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-GUI-Create-a-605d8c55/file/130831/1/link-label.ps1)

```
$Form                       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300)
$Form.Text                  = "Link Label Demo"
$Form.StartPosition         = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen

$LinkLabel1                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel
$LinkLabel1.Location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,50)
$LinkLabel1.Size            = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,20)
$LinkLabel1.LinkColor       = "BLUE"
$LinkLabel1.ActiveLinkColor = "RED"
$LinkLabel1.Text            = $(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Documents' -filter 'Return To Sender.docx').FullName
$LinkLabel1.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start('D:\Documents\Return To Sender.docx')})
$Form.Controls.Add($LinkLabel1) 

#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Or you just pass the output of this ...

```
print(str(route)+"\\"+str(file))
```

... to

```
Start-Process -FilePath $(print(str(route)+"\\"+str(file)))
```

... in your code or consolehost directly, just as the GUI is doing.